# Is my gear making me quieter or louder?

Tags: assassins-creed-unity

You can check out all your gear and it's bonuses using the Unity companion app, and I noticed that some gear has a +% effect and some a -%.

I'm curious to know if my gear is causing me to be louder, looking at the screenshot. However, it's the Phantom set, which includes more lock picks and overall gives a large bonus to your Stealth attribute, so why would it make me louder?

If it's a positive bonus, why isn't is a -% to noise?

[image: Unity companion app gear screen]

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking. Can you please explain further?

Comment: Why if restricted area detection time is a -65%, then why isn't high profile noise -18% for a stealth focused armour set?

Comment: it's hard to answer this because I'm not sure what Ubisoft means with %. I'm as confused as you are. I'll do some research and try to help you